# Find Joomla articles in FTP

Tags: joomla, ftp, filezilla

After 5 years I wants to reopen my old website. I did an Akeeba Backup at the time, but because it's so old, when I restore the page, some of the modules are so old, it can't even update. So my question is: Is it possible to withdraw the articles via FileZilla? I can't open them in backend.

I tried searching in filezilla and online but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From DB ADMIN**

You should log in into DB Admin like phpmyadmin or other. Then export the table __content..
If u say that is just five year..
I guess your Joomla would be 3.1 or above 2.7 version.

The DB table around that, there is not big different,
They dev Joomla just update the source to be more modern, PSR, rich and load all to be array and json to get modern php boost benefit.

So maybe you can import the DB just on version 3 clean install..
Or versi 2.5 clean install.
Then update from it to 3 or 4 version..

**FROM FILE ADMIN (FTP**)

If the DB is not on remote server, just localhost.
All DB will be stored on secure environment.
That secure environment is a first layer should be on outsite one level up on public_html or htdoc folder.
So you can search all folder, especially with prefix   `.(dot) before .[folderName]` like folder `.env .storage or .another.` Then if you get the DB engine you must do some trial error to move/copy them on your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Joomla, There is a blast from the past!

Joomla articles are likely to be stored in a mysql database within the jos_content (prefix may be different) tables.

I'm sorry, I'm unfamiliar with Akeeba but if you have access to a dump of your database you may be able to get that running and access it with a client of your choice.